# Xamarin: Сan't get data from the site

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, https

I'm trying to get information from the site. To do this, I request the entire page as a string, and then just look for the necessary info.
But unfortunately, I can't do it from the site I need. In the mobile app, I can get information from Yandex, Google and other sites, but I can't from my own. The program just freezes on the line `using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)` and in a few minutes I get the error "The operation has timed out"

But at the same time, when I use the same code in a regular application (not Xamarin), I get information from my site without problems.

I tried different parsers - the same thing.

Code:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string url = "https://yandex.ru";
            string url = "https://lhl-77.ru";
            string data = "";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                //var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                //var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                //var responseHtml = sr.ReadToEnd(); 

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader readStream = null;
                    if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                    {
                        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                    }
                    data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                    response.Close();
                    readStream.Close();

                    int found = data.IndexOf("<title>");
                    int found2 = data.IndexOf("</title>");

                    text.Text = "2";
                    qwe.Text = data.Substring(found + 7, 10);
                    qwe2.Text = "3";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: "just freezes" - where exactly is it freezing?  Which line?  Have you tested connectivity using the browser on the device?  Have you checked the logs for any relevant messages?  Have you tried adding any exception handling?

Comment: a timeout usually indicates a connectivity problem.  Did you verify connectivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the Internet connection, after that I got an error with the certificate, which was solved like this:

```
 request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really help anyone else resolve the problem you were experiencing above.  What specifically did you do to resolve the error in your question?  Did you add any code to handle the error condition that you could share to help others?

Comment: I just started going through the code with a debugger and got an error